# Como usar somente uma música da biblioteca do iPod app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou criando um simples alarme e gostaria de saber como "pegar" ou "apontar" para uma determinada musica escolhida pelo usuário, que está em sua biblioteca do iPod app.

Como eu poderia armazenar esse apontamento?

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma **[biblioteca](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)** para funções com o **iPod**. O item em questão que você vai precisar é o [`MPMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html) que é a própria música e ao utilizar o método `valueForProperty:` você consegue obter algumas propriedades que podem ser armazenadas como o "apontamento" que você precisa e utilizar para buscá-la novamente. Não tenho certeza se é possível armazenar o próprio `MPMediaItem`.

Um exemplo que está na própria documentação:

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];

for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
}
```

E que há a possibilidade de incluir **predicate** para filtrar ou se preferir, tem um [Media Picker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingtheMediaItemPicker/UsingtheMediaItemPicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH104-SW1), que funciona como seletor qualquer.